# How to rearrange collection view cell when device orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]

Collection view looks fine when in portrait mode. But when it landscape mode the cells do not rearrange .. they remain in the same place. [image]

I have added autolayout so that the collection view stretches to fill the screen and the collection view has a constant height constraint.

My view hierarchy is like this

View ->ScrollView->ContentView |--> Problematic collection view (one above notifications label)
                               |
                               |-> Tableview (one after after the notifications label)
                               |
                               |->Collection view (black space on top)

The code for the collection view is

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return 14;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (collectionView==self.offerCollectionView) {
    sliderCollectionInHomeScreen *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseIdForSlider"
                                                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    myCell.labelForShopName.text = [[self.arrayForOfferSlider objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"shop_name"];
    myCell.labelForOfferName.text = [[self.arrayForOfferSlider objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"offer_title"];
    myCell.offerImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.arrayForOfferSlider objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"img_url"]]]];

    ;


    return myCell;
}
```

Comment: Share some code, does it gives any error or warning?

Comment: It does not show any errors.

Comment: Share some code for collection view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct . But this has worked for me for the time being

```
-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrient{

//[self.categoryCollectionView reloadData];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout * lay =[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
    [lay setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
}
else{

    [lay setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
}


[self.CollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:lay];


}
```